# ASP - "$0" displaying as "{2}"

Tags: asp.net

We have a very strange error that we can't seem to solve. We have this code snippet on our .aspx page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="screenEnclosureCP" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlScreenEnclosure" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">$0 (No Screen Endorsement)</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5,000">$5,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="10,000">$10,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="15,000">$15,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="20,000">$20,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="25,000">$25,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="30,000">$30,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="35,000">$35,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="40,000">$40,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="45,000">$45,000</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="50,000">$50,000</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

That default value of "$0 (No Screen Endorsement)" displays as such:

[image: Screen Endorsement bug]

This error persists even if we use all HTML codes (`&#36;#48;`), a null character in between, etc. This errors occurs anywhere that "$0" appears.

Comment: is there anything in the codebehind that is setting the text of this list item? looks like someone failed a `string.Format()`. You could test this easily by totally removing the text in the markup

Comment: No, the text is static in the .aspx page.

Comment: I would double / triple check that. I'd also check to see if you have any javascript that could be changing it. Do a find for `{2}`, it's gotta be in there somewhere.

Comment: It's definitely somewhere in JavaScript. The only place that `{2}` shows up is in a few regular expressions for various jQuery plugins, and as a variable for jQuery Steps, but it doesn't seem to be changing/replacing anything. I'm trying to figure out if jQuery Steps has any effect.

Comment: It ended up being a .replace() method used in jQuery Steps. $0 is the matched string for that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the effect of some other code, either in the CodeBehind or in javascript, and not in any of the info provided in the question. Try doing a Find on `{2}` or `$0` and you should be able to find your culprit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I know that this was from a review, but this was the closest thing to an answer that we came to in the comments of the question.

Comment: The solution was to add another dollar sign, like so: `$$0`. It acts as an escape character.